# How to save LDA outputs to csv?

Tags: python, pandas, lda

```
    Y = data    
    cv = CountVectorizer(max_features=10, stop_words = my_stopwords, ngram_range=(1, 2), max_df=0.98)  
    cv_X = cv.fit_transform(Y)  
    word_col = cv.get_feature_names()  
    word_col[:10]

    lda_params = {'n_topics':[1]}  
    lda = LatentDirichletAllocation()  
    lda_grid = GridSearchCV(lda, lda_params)  
    lda_grid.fit(cv_X)  
    lda_grid.best_estimator_  
    lda_model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_topics=5, n_jobs=-1).fit(cv_X)  

    doctopic = lda_model.fit_transform(cv_X)  
    def topic_TopWords(model, feature_names, n_top_words):  
        for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):  
            print ("\n Topic {}: \n".format(topic_idx+1))  
            top_words = [feature_names[i] for i in topic.argsort()[::-1][:n_top_words]]  
            print (' '.join(sorted(top_words,key=len,reverse=True)))

    topic_TopWords(lda_model,word_col,15)   
mixture = [dict(lda_model[x]) for x in word_col]  
pd.DataFrame(mixture).to_csv("output.csv")
```

I am getting the following error

> TypeError: 'LatentDirichletAllocation' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Not sure what you're hoping to achieve with `dict(lda_model[x])`...

Comment: Your error is based on `lda_model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_topics=5, n_jobs=-1).fit(cv_X) 
` you cannot assign a classifier().fit to a variable